# Google api revoke token issue

Tags: authentication, token, logout, drive, google-api-js-client

I've created an application using google drive API to list and manage all my drive files.
Everything goes fine, except the log out part. I've searched for two days for a solution without a result.

The following is code related to login and works fine:

```
  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
        'immediate': true,
        'authuser': '-1'
      }, handleAuthResult);
  }

  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {   
    var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
      loadDriveApi();
    } else {
      authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
    }
  }


  function handleAuthClick(event) { 
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
      handleAuthResult);
    return false;
  }

  function loadDriveApi() {
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', listFiles);
  }
```

I'm able to login and work with files, but when I try to logout with following I get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

```
$(document).on('click', '.logout', function(){
    var token = gapi.auth.getToken();  
    if (token) {
      var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
      if (accessToken) {     
          var revokeToken = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + accessToken;
          jQuery.getJSON(revokeToken).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data); 
            }).error(function(message) {
                console.error('error' + message); 
            }).complete(function() {
                console.log('completed!'); 
            });              
      }
    }
    gapi.auth.setToken(null);
    gapi.auth.signOut();      
  });
```

In Google Developers Console I've regitred my website to Authorized JavaScript origins.

Thanks